# Django formsets do not save images

Tags: django, forms, image, view, formset

I have an addpage form where users have to add their card for boots model. Below i will show to you my code.

SO! The problem is my images are not saving at my media directory at all. And so one of the
consequences Card.model doesn't take this images, but rest of the form fields working perfictly. Sorry for my bad english and asking for support!!

Models.py

```
class Card(models.Model):
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Категория')
brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Бренд')
boots_model = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True, verbose_name='Модель бутс')
description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Описание')
slug = AutoSlugField('URL', max_length=70, db_index=True, unique_with=('created', 'boots_model', 'size', 'color', 'price'), populate_from=instance_boots_model, slugify=slugify_value)
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='Цена')
# image = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/%Y/%m/%d/", blank=True, verbose_name='Загрузите фотографии')
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
size = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, verbose_name='Размер')
NEW = 'new'
USED = 'old'
STATEMENT_CHOICES = [
    (NEW, 'Новые'),
    (USED, 'Б/У')
]
statement = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=STATEMENT_CHOICES, default=USED, verbose_name='Состояние')
color = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True, verbose_name='цвет')


class Meta:
    ordering = ('-created',)
    verbose_name = 'Объявление'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Объявления'

def __str__(self):
    return self.boots_model

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = uuslug(self.slug, instance=self)
    super(Card, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    category = self.category
    brand = self.brand
    return reverse('card', args=[str(category.slug), str(brand.slug), str(self.slug)])

class ImagePhoto(models.Model):
    directory = models.ForeignKey(Card, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_custom_directory, blank=True, verbose_name='Фотографии')

def __str__(self):
        return str(self.image)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Фотографии'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Фотографии'
```

forms.py

```
class AddCardForm(forms.ModelForm):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['category'].empty_label = "Категория не выбрана"
    self.fields['brand'].empty_label = "Бренд не выбран"
    # self.fields['boots_model'].help_text = "Старайтесь вводить полное название обуви"

class Meta:
    model = Card
    fields = ['category', 'brand', 'boots_model', 'description', 'price', 'size', 'statement', 'color']
    help_texts = {
        'boots_model': 'Название на английском языке с цифрами\nНапример: PREDATOR 18.3 FG',
    }
    widgets = {
        'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 30, 'rows': 5, 'placeholder': 'Введите что-нибудь'}),

    }

def clean_boots_model(self):
    cyrillic_letters = 'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ'
    boots_model = self.cleaned_data['boots_model']
    for c in boots_model:
        if c in cyrillic_letters:
            raise ValidationError('Допускается название только на английском языке и цифры')
    return boots_model

class AddimgForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ImagePhoto
        fields = ['image']

        widgets = {
            'image': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}),
        }
```

and finally views.py

```
def add_page(request):
MyFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Card, ImagePhoto, fields=('image',), extra=0)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AddCardForm(request.POST)
    formset = MyFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES,)
    if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
        c = form.save(commit=False)
        c.save()

        for f in formset:
            pic = ImagePhoto(directory=c, image=f.cleaned_data('image'))
            pic.save()

        return redirect('home')


else:
    form = AddCardForm()
    formset = MyFormSet(queryset=ImagePhoto.objects.none())

return render(request, 'mysite/addpage.html', {'formset': formset, 'form': form, 'title': 'Добавить объявление'})
```

also addcard.html

```
    <form action="{% url 'addpage' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="addpage-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h1>Разместить объявление</h1>
    {% for p in form %}
    {% if p.help_text %}<p class="help-text">{{ p.help_text|linebreaksbr }}{% endif %}
    <p><label class="form-label" for="{{ form.id_for_label }}">{{ p.label }}: </label>{{ p }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    <input type="file" name = "files" multiple />{% for f in formset %}
    <div class="form-error">{{ f.errors }}</div>
{% endfor %}
    <div class="addpage-button-submit">
        <button type="submit">Добавить объявление</button>
    </div>    
    </form>
```

Comment: Can I see your root urls.py ?

Comment: if your image field deliberately commented out in class Card?